# Show all products on one page in admin panel - Opencart

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to show all products on one page in the admin panel of Opencart. I tried to find in the admin folder any file that contains show product limit but didn't find it. Maybe someone knows how to change the standard limit from 20 to any other bigger limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OC ADMIN go...
`System->Settings->Choose your store->Options` and set quantity in "Default Items Per Page (Admin)" field.